# Grammar of との, what is the meaning

Tags: grammar, translation

So here in this sentence below "との" was used 2 times.
What does との standfor? Can someone please explain it to me?

> これまで数多くのアニメ作品**との**コラボを実現してきた痛印堂には、「好きなアニメ**との**コラボは嬉しいけど、自分の好きなキャラクターがいない！」「メインキャラクターだけでなく違う子もお願いします！」などの声が届いており、その要望に応えるべく今回の「ガールズ＆パンツァー」痛印第2弾が実現しました。

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally speaking:

〜と links to a following **verb** (or other predicate)
　　〜との links to a following **noun** (or noun equivalent)

That's generally what の does—indicates a relationship to a following noun:

> 海**へ**　行く　　The particle へ links 海 to the following **verb** 行く
>   　海**への**道　　　The particle の links 海へ to the following **noun** 道

In English, we use word order instead of a particle:

> go [ **to** the sea ]
>   　the road [ **to** the sea ]

We can tell that the ***to***-phrase relates to the verb ***go*** or to the noun ***road*** because they're next to each other.  But that doesn't work in Japanese—you need to specify that it relates to a noun by adding の.

Likewise, in your example, 好きなアニメ**と** needs **の** to relate to the following noun, コラボ.  In English we could just say "collaboration [ **with** 〜 ]", but in Japanese you need to add **の**.