# Difference between について and につき

Tags: grammar, verbs

What exactly are the differences between using について and につき? In the following sentences, my grammar book says they are not interchangeable, but I don´t quite understand why. Thank you very much for your help.

> この記事に**ついて**のご意見をお聞かせください。
>
> 新しい事業計画**につき**、これから御説明いたします。

Comment: Well, the first one is really **〜についての**, in which case they are not interchangeable.

Comment: For the usage of the の, these threads might be of some help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17739/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33606/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/9831

Answer (score 1):

> この記事**についての**ご意見をお聞かせください。
>   Please tell me your opinion **about** this article.
>
> 新しい事業計画**につき**、これから御説明いたします。
>   Now I'd like to talk **about** the new project plan.

Not interchangeable in the first sentence due to the の after について.

But this would be fine:

> 新しい事業計画**について**、これから御説明いたします。
>   Now I'd like to talk **about** the new project plan.

- Also, 「につき」has an additional common usage
  which isn't interchangeable with「について」:

[image]

Here it is the same as saying, 「工事中**なので**」or「工事中**のため**」

"**Due to** Construction" / "**Because of** Construction"
"Please Refrain from Parking"

Comment: So after につき it´s necessary to have a comma, and it´s not possible to use it with の? In all cases? But with について both are possible (using a comma after or using の)?

Comment: Yes, I don't think につきの is grammatically correct . Commas don't really matter as much in Japanese though. I only use them because I like them so much. について and についての are both correct.