# What's the difference between ぬきで & ぬきの and 入りの & 入りで?

Tags: particles

I can't find the difference and in the book that I use there is no explanation.

---

Context: It is about ordering food. I have two sentences:

> ミルクと砂糖**入りの**紅茶はいくらですか。
>   ホットコーヒーをミルクと砂糖**入りで**ください。

Comment: What's the context? Are you talking about phrases for ordering food, like 「ピクルスぬきのハンバーガー」 vs 「ハンバーガー、ピクルスぬきで」、「ワサビいりの鉄火巻き」vs 「鉄火巻き、ワサビ入りで」??

Comment: Yes, It is about ordering food, I have two sentence. One is ミルクと砂糖入りの紅茶はいくらですか。And the second one is ホットコーヒーをミルクと砂糖入りでください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, ～で is always adverbial (i.e., modifies a *verb*), whereas ～の always connects to the following *noun*. In English this distinction is not always clear because "with ～", "to ～", "in ～" and so on [can modify both a noun and a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17739/5010).

- ワサビ抜きで寿司を食べた。　I ate sushi without wasabi; I ate, without wasabi, sushi.
- ワサビ抜きで寿司　(sounds like an incomplete sentence fragment because there is no verb for 抜きで to modify)
- ワサビ抜きの寿司を食べた。　I ate sushi without wasabi; I ate wasabi-free sushi.
- ワサビ抜きの寿司　wasabi-free sushi (noun phrase)

When you order something, you can say, for example:

> ミルク入りでください。
>   ミルク入りでお願いします。
>   With milk, please.

...because ください/お願いします is a verb. You can omit this verb and say this simply:

> ミルク入り**で**。
>   With milk (, please).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide the sentence in the book to get a nice answer.

Probably your book contains the sentence like “彼抜きの会議はつまらない。” or “彼抜きで会議はつまらない” The former normally implies “the meeting without him is boring.”. The latter normally implies “Having a meeting without him is boring.”

Hopefully you could provide some sentences for the distinction 入りの/入りで.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It´s my first time posting a question. I have two sentence. One is ミルクと砂糖入りの紅茶はいくらですか。And the second one is ホットコーヒーをミルクと砂糖入りでください。

Comment: You need to add it into your question to get a nice answer. You can edit your question.