# 仕事をする上で大切なのは、周りと**の**コミュニケーションです。What's the function of の here?

Tags: particle-の

I have no clue what の has to do in the sentence.
Isn't 周り**とコミュニケーション**です。enough?

Comment: Could we get your translation to see how you understand the relationship between 周り and コミュニケーション and their roles in the sentence?

Comment: 周りとコミュニケーションです is a common mistake English speakers make. Does this answer your question? [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33605/using-%e3%81%ae-with-%e3%81%a8-%e3%81%a7-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7)

Comment: Also related: [Grammar of との, what is the meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17738/5010)

Comment: @sbkgs4686
'周りとコミュニケーションです=communicating with the surrounding environment(colleaugues, customers...etc)' right?
When の is added, i don't know what it adds to the meaning.

Comment: The 'verb' (です) in your sentence is acting as a copula to say that "a is b". This makes the entire predicate a noun phrase. As the posts narutoさん shared mention, a noun in Japanese cannot be qualified directly by certain particles like と, で, へ, まで, etc.; the particle needs to be followed by の in order to allow for it to qualify a noun.

Comment: 周りとコミュニケーションです is plain wrong. の adds nothing to the meaning; it's just a mandatory particle to make this sentence grammatical.

Comment: No one said it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

NICE Question.

So the の is in it's possessive functionality here.

The Communication is that which is had between the speaker and those around them.

This is a common form when talking about the state of some relationship or some interaction

EX：

君との生活はできない

あいつらとの関係は上手くいかないね。

親との考え方が違うんだ

Hope that helps

Comment: 親との考え方が違うんだ doesn't make sense. 親と考え方が違うんだ or 親との考え方の違いがあるんだ does.

Comment: Good call, 親との考え方の違いがあるんだ is right, thank you.