# Am i translating this right?

Tags: grammar

Hi i was just wondering if i can get feedback if i understood what this sentence is saying.

sentence:

> これで人との会話シミュレーションは完了

my rough translation:

> With this, person and its conversation simulation is completed

I'm confused why there is a と and what i came up with was the speaker is trying to sound fancy and say something like, "people and their conversations."

Answer (score 3):

You’ve got the part but aren’t assembling it correctly and you’re zeroing in the very thing that’s getting in your way.

人と話し合う

would mean to speak with someone. In your sentence, the verb would be

会話する

To say, have a *conversation with someone * you would say

人と会話する

But 会話 can be used as a noun too. In that case you cannot say

人と会話

That’s not grammatically complete. To complete it you join the two parts with の resulting in

人との会話

At this point you’re almost done.

To say *this person* you would have to say この人.

But what you have is これ+で which means “by means of this”.

So the sentence can be rendered as

> *With this, simulation of a conversation with a person is complete*

You should note that the final copulate だ has been omitted.

**Regarding the use of と and の**

English and some other Germanic languages stand apart in how prepositional constructs can be used to modify nouns.   So in English we can say

> A conversation with someone

And it makes perfectly good sense.
However there are languages don’t allow these sorts of constructs. To convey the same idea a relative clause can be used:

> A conversation that is with someone

To our English-language ear this sounds cringy. However not in a language like Japanese. The particle の in Japanese is what creates the glue syntactically and semantically joining 会話 and 人と. Resulting in

> 人との会話

There are other examples.

> The letter to my friend is on the desk.

In Japanese this must be rendered as

> 友達への手紙は机の上にある

This の in 友達への手紙 is serving the same role as the の in 人との会話.

Comment: ok noted but im just confused with why is there a と

Comment: と is the particle expressing the idea of “with” when you say you’re having a conversation *with* someone.

Comment: sorry i phrased it wrong i know what the と particle does but with the の  will it be translated to person and their conversations?

Comment: @user38996 See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17738/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010

Comment: thank you so much